# Creating table from another table

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a table2 from table1.

I don't need all rows from table1. I just need the table structure alone  of table1 and want that same structure in table2.

What is query to create this in sql server 2008?

Comment: Don't you rather want a view instead of anothet table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply

```
SELECT TOP 1 * INTO table2 FROM table1
```

That will put only the first row of table 1 into the new one which of course you can easily delete again.

Of course: this will only get you a table with *similar columns* but it will *not* have any `INDEX` or `PRIMARY KEY` definitions or an `identity` column (if that existed in table1).

**Edit:**

To get the table without any data - as Surender Raja points out below - you can supply the impossible condition `1=0`:

```
SELECT * INTO table2 FROM table1 WHERE 1=0
```

Comment: Yes. This helps. Also I used this query select * into updated_emp from emp where 1=0 and it works.. but  what happens if I give 1=0 in where clause.